# I'm using the property findelements with selenium and C#, but it keeps giving the same error

Tags: c#, selenium

This is a part of the code that i was trying to use to get the respective elements, but it keeps giving me the following error:

> System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement]or
>   others identical

This is also shown in a datagridview, in her rows.

```
IList<IWebElement> ruas = Gdriver.FindElements(By.ClassName("search-title"));
String[] AllText = new String[ruas.Count];
int i = 0;
foreach (IWebElement element in ruas)
{

     AllText[i++] = element.Text;
     table.Rows.Add(ruas);     
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about the error?  The error's exact type name (including its namespace before it) and the exact error message?

Comment: my error is shown when my code goes to the respective site http://www.codigo-postal.pt/ and picks  elements to the datagridview and in the rows appears this error:  System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how i answered my own question:

```
IList<string> all = new List<string>();
        foreach (var element in Gdriver.FindElements(By.ClassName("search-title")))
        {
            all.Add(element.Text);
            table.Rows.Add(element.Text);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing is: as far as I understand the elements you are talking about are not contained in table. Its a list: `<ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">...` (considering the comment you left with site link)

If you want to find those elements you can use the code below:

```
var elements = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("ul.list-inline > li > a"));

// Here you can iterate though links and do whatever you want with them
foreach (var element in elements)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element.Text);
}

// Here is the collection of links texts
var linkNames = elements.Select(e => e.Text).ToList();
```

Considering the error you get, I may assume that you are using [DataGridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx) for storing collected data, which is terribly incorrect. [DataGridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx) is used for viewing data in MVC application. There is no standard Selenium class for storing table data. There are multiple approaches for this, but I can't suggest you any because I don't know your what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: First of all thanks, if the link was this [link](http://www.codigo-postal.pt/?cp4=4710&cp3=) and you were to get the first frase, those in blue, of each address, what would you do?

Comment: @PedroAlvim, this is not a table either. The approach for getting elements texts you provided in the new link is the very same. The only difference will be in selector. In second case it will be CssSelector: "`div.places > p > span > a.search-title`" that uses same code that I already provided.

Comment: @PedroAlvim, also a good article about selectors in Selenium is [link](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors). It contains basic cases. When you done with this one, you can learn more advanced cases at W3C: [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)